# How to implement a custom Shader in Android

Tags: android

I would like to draw a circle filled with blended color with gradient. However, the existing android.graphics.Shader subclasses cannot meet my need. In short, I would like to control the color of each pixel in the circle myself. Is it possible to implement a custom Shadar object by extending android.graphics.Shader?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about subclassing `android.graphics.Shader`

But if you are using OpenGl ES 2.0 you can write your own Shader using [GLSL](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/) which gives you very high flexibilty.

Maybe have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850025/shader-for-android-opengl-es) question.