# How to Create Complex Android Animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I've been surfing the web for android animation, and all what I found was the XML ones (transition,scale,...) but these simple functions cannot create complex animation. So how can I do so?
For example, I want "fireworks" in my application, so how I can animate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: get an image of the firework, use the method you mentioned to change position on screen/size/etc of the firework image. you can use listeners to, for example, set sparks going off of the firework at certain places on the screen at a certain time

Comment: read about `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Answer (score 0):

For something like that you'll need a pixel or vertex shader, written in opengl. There is a small example here on how to load one: [Shader for Android OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850025/shader-for-android-opengl-es)

But I'll guess you'll find more if you google Android pixel shaders or something like that. Do you have any concrete questions? What are you going to do?

Comment: Well, I'm making a game, and it has several modes, so every mode should have animation that is related to the mode. So fireworks is one of them. I was thinking also of animation on the main menu, so I had an idea if I could design something on 3DMax, so I can put, is it possible?